# Начальные настройки в Android приложении

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences

Здравствуйте.

Столкнулся с проблемой при работе с SharedPreferences. Мне надо задать начальные настройки, которые потом пользователь может поменять в отдельной активити, но я что-то не понимаю, как сделать так чтобы настройки не были всегда начальными.

Т.е при первом запуске в главной активити я устанавливаю значения, но потом даже при изменении настроек в активити Setting при повторном запуске будут те же начальные значения, что я задал в главной активити.

В общем я запутался.

Comment: покажите код, который обновляет SharedPreferences

Comment: Возможно я по своему понял вашу задачу. Но как я понимаю вы хотите, чтобы при самом первом запуске приложения задавались определённые настройки. И чтобы эти настройки задавались только первый раз, а в последующие запуски либо оставались теми же либо пользователь задавал свои? Тогда я бы добавил в SharedPreferences дополнительный параметр, который бы указывал, что стартовые настройки уже были заданы. Ну или другой вариант - проверять существуют ли уже ключи стартовых настроек, если нет, значит настройки ещё никогда не устанавливались, а если существуют, значит не трогать.

Comment: Вообще при чтении любого типа данных из настроек указывается дефолтное значение вторым параметром, которое будет использовано, если ранее в настройки по этому ключу ничего не записывали.

Answer (score 2):

Структуру преференсов принято задавать в XML файле, который принято помещать в каталог *res/xml*, типа:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <android.support.v7.preference.EditTextPreference
        android:key="@string/pref_myTextPref"
        android:title="@string/myText"
        android:summary=""
        android:persistent="true"
        android:defaultValue="15"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:numeric="integer"
        />
</android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

Начальное значение задается через `android:defaultValue`

P.S. Здесь приведен пример через compat библиотеку, если не позволяет религия, есть и другие стандартные классы (правда они работают только для старших версий Android'а)

Answer (score 0):

1. Создайте класс `public class App extends Application`.
2. Пропишите этот класс в манифесте для приложения. Этот класс всегда будет стартовать первым. Для этого внутри тега application добавьте `android:name=".App"`

> ```
> <application
>             android:icon="@drawable/your_ico"
>             android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
>             android:name=".App"
>             >
>     ...
>     </application>
> ```

3. Переопределите метод `onCreate();` в классе App Добавьте в него загрузку настроек. Если они пустые (ещё не создавались) - создайте их из констант и сохраните.
4. Если они не пустые (уже созданые) - не перезаписываем.